# Which format of OAuth redirect_uri pass in instagram.....?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I am beginner of ios. I want to integrate instagram in my apps. I have already register in instagram. When I go to manage client I have pass the OAuth redirect_uri but it is give error of You must enter an absolute URI that starts with http://, https://. It is in I have pass the perfect uri like example.. http://abc.com but it is return error. please give any suggestion which is apply in my app.